# what is a correct update statement for modifying a attribute of a row entry given row id?

Tags: mysql, sql, actionscript-3

I hope someone can help me with a "stupid" question. I see many sql update related question, but still haven't come across one that works for me. I am working in action script and have a code that inserts empty table entries for later retrieval and modification. During the table creation I define the table (items) to have entries that looks like:

```
"items(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, address TEXT, title TEXT)";
```

I make an insert:

```
"insert into items VALUES (null, null, null, null)"
```

The lastInsertRowID returned after the insert is stored on an object called itemInfo (as an attribute rowID) as I intend to modify row entries later with a separate function.

From what I have read, should´t this be an acceptable update-query?

```
"update items set name=" + "hey" + " where rowid=" + itemInfo.rowID;
```

The intent with the query is to update the name attribute for a particular entry in the database, but it does not seem to work for me.

What is a legal update-statement to modify the name attribute for a given rowID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed enclosing your string with the `'`.  How about:

```
"update items set name = '" + "hey" + "' where rowid = " + itemInfo.rowID;
```